# Find the solution of $y'''+y''-y'-4y=2-2x$, $y(1)=\frac{1}{2}, y'(1)=y''(1)=0$ by using Laplace transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to find the solution of $y'''+y''-y'-4y=2-2x\ $, $y(1)=\frac{1}{2},\  y'(1)=y''(1)=0$ by using Laplace transformation. When I try to solve this exercise by appling Laplace transformation I get that $$L\{y(t)\}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{s^2+s-1}{s(s^2+s-1)-4}-\frac{2}{s(s^3+s^2-s-4)}-\frac{2}{s^2(s^3+s^2-s-4)} .$$ The problem is that $s^3+s^2-s-4 $ has not only real roots but complex roots, too, and of course I can not find them analitic.  Does anyone has any ideas what's the next step? Thanks!!

Comment: Laplace tarnsform needs $y(0)$ you should change the variable as $z=x-1$ and rewrite the DE before to apply Laplace Transform

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Aryadeva I changed my independent variable by making the linear transformation $z=x-1$. Then, the derivatives doesn't change and I have the equation $y'''+y''-y'-4y=2z$ with the same conditions just on $0$ this time
 . So, I find $L\{y(t)\}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{s^2+s-1}{s(s^2+s-1)-4}-\frac{2}{s(s^3+s^2-s-4)}. $ Again, I have the same problem although is simplier than previous.

Comment: It wont change the nature of the problem but it's more correct the integral, of the Laplace Transform has the bound at zero not one...  There is nothing you can do about the roots they are complicated that's it not your fault... Konstantinos try using Wolfram Alpha to find the roots